# Kendo grid - how to apply border to entire row based on a condition

Tags: jquery, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

How to apply border to the entire row based on certain conditions either on databound event or on column template?

Comment: I made this an actual question. Do you have any code to show what you have tried in order to make this happen? If so, edit the question and add that, please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So after searching the internet for hours yesterday trying to find a simple solution I discovered my own.  This is to style an individual CELL not a row but still very relevant. This scenario involves coloring an individual kendo grid cell based on the value within the cell.  I discovered that you don't have to make the changes on the dataBound function but within the kendo.template itself. In columns, you add the kendo.template to the field you want to customize.  Next add the conditional expression to the class.

Super simple and works like a hot damn! Find full example here: http://dojo.telerik.com/UhUzi

```
$("#grid").kendoGrid({
    dataSource: dataSource,
    pageable: true,
    height: 430,
    toolbar: ["create", "save", "cancel"],
    columns: [
      "ProductName",
      { field: "UnitPrice", title: "Unit Price", format: "{0:c}", width: 110 },
      { field: "UnitsInStock", title: "Units In Stock", width: 110 },
      { template: kendo.template('<div class=#= Discontinued ? "Discontinued_True" : "Discontinued_False" #>#= Discontinued ? "true" : "false" #</div>'), width: 110 },
      { command: "destroy", title: "&nbsp;", width: 100 }],
    editable: true
  });
```

CSS Style:

```
.Discontinued_False {
    background-color: green;
    color: transparent;
 }
.Discontinued_True{
    background-color: Crimson;
    color: transparent;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Using databound event

```
 dataBound: function (e) {
                    // get all rows
                    var rows = e.sender.tbody.children();
                    // this is current data item
                    var dataItem = e.sender.dataItem(row);
                    for (var j = 0; j < rows.length; j++) {
                        var row = $(rows[j]);
                        //your condition here
                        // if (dataItem.Field <= 5)
                        //get all columns
                        row.find('td').each(function (column, td) {

                            //border must be added for each td
                            $(td).css('border-bottom', '1px solid black');
                        });
```

Answer (score 1):

The following article discusses the described scenario:

http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/controls/data-management/grid/how-to/Layout/style-rows-cells-based-on-data-item-values

Column templates will hardly help in styling the entire row, because they do not provide access to the row and cell elements. That's why consider a `rowTemplate` and `altRowTemplate`, or row/cell style manipulations in `dataBound`.

http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/grid